# How to analyse stability of a limit cycle for this example?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Consider the following system in polar coordinates
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=(r^2-1)(2 r \cos(\phi)-1), \\
\frac{d \phi}{dt}=1.$$
The question is if the limit cycle $r=1$ is stable, and what is the region of attraction.

Simulations show that this limit cycle is attractive for $0<r<1$, and for $1<r<r+\epsilon$ with sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$. However, I cannot establish a strict proof and analysis.

Comment: This problem is a lot harder than it looks. The perturbative approach does not give the answer (at least, not after some significant work). The region of attraction is best described in Cartesian coordinates:  roughly it is the whole second quatdrant ($x<0,y>0$), plus the triangular wedge bounded by the $-X$ axis above and a linefrom the origin at an angle of $37.89^\circ$ against the $X$ axis below, plus an area bounded by a nearly quarter-circular curve in quadrant IV  of radius roughly 1.01r-1.066, plus the veritical half-strip $0< x<1,y>0$.

Comment: Mark Fischler, How did you find these regions?

Comment: Turned it into single ODE for $r(t)$, with a parameter $\phi_0$. Wrote a quick numerical integration, running on $t\in[0,4\pi]$. When in the region of attraction but near the boundary, typically $r(t)$ has a sharp peak somewhere around $t=\pi$ but plunges to nearly $1$, sometimes taking a second small bounce at around $8\pi/3$.  For fixed $\phi_0$, when $r$ exceeds the boundary value, solution blows up super-exponentially with $t$.  Plotted critical $r$ versus $\phi_0$.